# Problem with $u$-substitution for the integral $-e^{4x}/4x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve the DE:
$$y''- 4y = \dfrac { e^{2x}}x$$
using variation of parameters method. While trying to get the particular solution I ended up with $u_1'(x)=1/4x$ which is $\ln(x)/4$ when integrated and in case of $u_2'(x)=-e^{4x}/4x$ I ran into some problems.

I integrated $u_2'(x)$ using $u$-substitution where $u=4x.$ Making appropriate substitutions into the integral:

$$-\int e^u\cdot\frac1u \cdot \frac14 \,du = \frac{-1}4 \int \frac{e^u}u \,du$$

I am not sure what to do with this integral from hereon. I looked up the answer for u2(x) which looks something like what I circled below and it doesn't make sense to me. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: You can't express that integral with elementary functions thats why the book keep the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The integral given by the book is using the expression of $u_2$ before the substitution (they kept the integral form because we cannot simplify further this integral).

If you want to do a substitution, be careful : you should add bounds to the integral and change bounds with the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $$\int \frac{e^x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. It is called the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).